# real and imaginary part of f(x)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

If

> > $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}=e^{(\lambda_{R}+i\lambda_{I})x}$, then
> >     $Re(f(x))=e^{\lambda_{R}x}$ and $Im(f(x))=e^{\lambda_{I}x}$.
> >
> > When
> >     ${
> > f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1+\frac{\lambda x}{n} \right)^n
> > }\quad(1)$,
> >
> > then how can we write the real and imaginary part of f(x) for equation (1)?
> >
> > note that: $\lambda=\lambda_{R}+i\lambda_{I}$

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't Re$(f(x))$ and Im$(f(x))$. If $a$ and $b$ are real then Re$(e^{a+bi})=e^a\cos b$ and Im$(e^{a+bi})=e^a\sin b$.

In your example $a=\lambda_R x$ and $b=\lambda_I x$ so Re$(f(x)=e^{\lambda_R x}\cos(\lambda_Ix)$ etc.

Comment: >>Thanx Lord, can we write real and img part of f(x) for equation (1)?